# How to implement a "contains" function for linked lists in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm currently doing an assignment for uni and I need to find the sum of a graph.

To do this I believe I need a linked list that I can use to remember which nodes have been visited. I have the linkedlist working correctly but I can't get a contains function to work. This is the code I have:

```
struct listnode
{
  struct N *val;
  struct listnode *next;
};


int contains(struct listnode *head,struct N* value)
{
  struct listnode *current = head;
  while (current)
  {
    if ((current -> val) == value)
    {
      return 1;
    }
    current = current -> next;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

note: N is a node of the graph.

Can anyone see any problems with what I'm doing?

EDIT: contains function should return 1 when N *value is in the list, 0 otherwise

EDIT2:

I have a push function:

```
void push(struct listnode *head,struct N *value)
{
  if (head)
  {
    struct listnode *current = head;
    while (current->next)
    {
      current = current -> next;
    }
    current->next = malloc(sizeof(struct listnode*));
    current->next->val = value;
    current->next->next = NULL;
  }
  else
  {
    head = malloc(sizeof(struct listnode*));
    if (head)
    {
      head -> val = value;
      head -> next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
      printf("error");
      exit(0);
    }
  }
}
```

and I want the following line to return 1:

```
contains(push(visited,p),p);
```

where p is a pointer to a struct N and visited is my global linked list

EDIT3:

this is my final sum function that I believe should work, but doesnt because of contains.

```
long sum(struct N *p)
{
  if (p)
  {
    if (contains(visited,p) == 0) //if p hasnt been visited
    {
      push(visited,p); //make it visited
      return (p -> data) + sum(p -> x) + sum(p -> y) + sum(p -> z);
    }
    else
    {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: *I can't get a contains function to work* - What do you mean cant get it working, what is it supposed to do? What does it actually do?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox it should return 1 when N *value is in the list and 0 otherwise

Comment: Are you sure that comparing pointers is valid? Maybe they are different pointers with the same contents?

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst I thought comparing pointers would check that the addresses are the same?

Comment: Yes, it will, but sometimes people confuse pointers and contents like thinking two different `char*` pointers that happen to point to the same word will compare equal, so I was just checking.

Comment: what is inside of your `struct N` that is being compared?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? Please provide a code example with say a two-item list that shows this is not working.

Comment: @toastedDeli Your edit didn't help all that much(your push function is quite buggy, though, so perhaps that is your actual problem, and not your contains() function) . You should post the complete(but minimal part that shows the error) code you have which calls your conains() function so the people looking at that code can compile, run it and observe the same error that you see on your screen.

Comment: Well, there's your problem. `push` doesn't return a new `head` (or anything at all for that matter).

Comment: @toasteDeli Not if you pass in head as a NULL pointer. It also does not return a value that you could pass to your contains function. But the point still stands I cannot compile and run your code. Perhaps someone fixes the issues in the push() function, but you have yet more issues in the other code we cannot see, and its a rabbithole that will never end.

Comment: As @MadPhysicist suggests in his answer, another error, less easy to find, is the `malloc(sizeof(struct listnode*));` used in the `push()` function. In fact, only a pointer to the node is allocated instead of a structure it-self. Use `malloc(sizeof(struct listnode));` to store each node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your contains function appears to be fine. The issue is that you are always passing a `NULL` list to it, which is caused by a faulty `push` function. You need a return in `push`, or to pass in a pointer with one more level of indirection, so you can assign to `head` outside of `push`. One more possible improvement is to notice that no matter what you pass in, the `malloc` and initialization of a new node is actually the same.

Finally, the main issue, that is really the most likely to cause a segfault is the fact that you are allocating enough space for a pointer to a node, not for the node itself.

Here is an example:

```
#ifdef BY_INDIRECTION
  #define RET_TYPE void
  #define IN_TYPE struct listnode **
#else
  #define RET_TYPE struct listnode *
  #define IN_TYPE struct listnode *
#endif

RET_TYPE push(IN_TYPE head, struct N *value)
{
  struct listnode *current, **next;
  if(head)
  {
    for(current = head; current->next; current = current->next) ;
    next = &(current->next);
  }
  else
  {
#ifdef BY_INDIRECTION
    next = head;
#else
    next = &head;
#endif
  }

  *next = malloc(sizeof(struct listnode));
  if(!*next) {
      printf("error");
      exit(0);
  }
  (*next)->val = value;
  (*next)->next = NULL;

#ifndef BY_INDIRECTION
  return head
#endif
}
```

I have included both suggestions here. If you want to read the one where we use indirection (pass in a `listnode **` and have `void` return), choose the path where `BY_INDIRECTION` is defined. If you want to have `head` returned (and pass in just a regular `listnode *`) read the path where `BY_INDIRECTION` is not defined.

The latter approach has a return value, so it can be used to write a shortened form like `if(contains(push(head, value), value)) { ... }`. The former approach does not, so you would have to do

```
push(&head, value);
if(contains(head, value)) { ... }
```

I would recommend using the indirect approach regardless because there are very few instances that you would want to check for containment *after* putting in a value.

Comment: Your answer should be simplified to explain how to manage the linked-list of OP. In your example, the case `BY_INDIRECTION` doesn't match with the request of `contains(push(visited,p),p);`.

Comment: I addressed that in my last sentence. Will make more explicit

Answer (score 0):

This comparison:

```
if ((current -> val) == value)
```

it's comparing pointers. If you call your `contains()` function this way...

```
...
struct N val_to_find;
...
result = contains (list, &val_to_find);
```

You will never find the value, even if the contents of `val_to_find` are the same as the contents of any struct whose pointer is stored in the list.

If your intention for `contains()` is to find nodes that have the same data, and not just the same pointers, I'd suggest you something like this:

```
if (struct_n_comparing_function (current -> val, value) == EQUAL) ...
```

Where `struct_n_comparing_function` should have the following prototype:

```
int struct_n_comparing_function (struct N *a, struct N *b);
```

which compares the contents of the two structs pointed by `a` and `b` and return `EQUAL` if all the fields of the struct pointed by `a` have the same value as the fields of struct pointed by `b`.

Comment: OP is looking for exact pointer comparison, not value comparison.